# Java calling C calling Java

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I want to call a C funcion from Java using JNI. And in the C function, I want to create a JVM and call some Java objects. When I try to create the JVM, JNI_CreateJavaVM returns -1.

So, I want to know if it is possible to do this. The C code is compiled to create a .so file (in linux), and the Java code calls the function in the .so file.

Any example doing Java->C->Java will be useful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately its not possible. You can only have one JVM per process, and you're already in a JVM process.

Comment: Doesn't have to be, it depends on what you want to do. As some of the other posts say, you can access java objects from your process through the C JNI functions.

Answer (score 2):

I can not see the point in that Java-->C-->Java.

If you can call C from Java, then you can call Java from Java after your C function returns.

[Excelsion xFunction](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/xfunction.html) is an easy and reliable library for calling C from Java. It handles the weird JNI stuff giving you a simpler interface.

Comment: There is a time and place where such a feature is useful. I'm not convinced calling back to an external VM is a good idea though.

Comment: It is useful in some situations. For example, you may create a thread running with the C code (Java-->C) and later use C-->Java for callbacks.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to create a second JVM? You can't create a second JVM, but you can access Java classes from C code. See [Accessing Java Objects](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/design.html#wp1253).

Answer (score 1):

I can't see why some people consider this useless. In fact, the Java -> C -> Java scenario is very common when you get into Android game programming:

1. The Android app starts from some boilerplate code written in Java (using the SDK)
2. A new thread is started to run the main logic of the game, which is written in C / C++ for efficiency (and the easier access to [OpenGL ES](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/))
3. The C / C++ code calls some Java methods for the required functionalities

The reason why it is necessary to use the [SDK (Java)](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) is that most of the Android APIs are provided only in Java! The [NDK (C / C++)](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) only provides a slim Linux environment (think it as "Standard C Library" + "Standard C++ Library" + "Cutdown Version of Linux System Libraries"). For example, if you want to integrate your app with [AdMob (Google Ads)](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/), or [In-app Billing (Google Payment)](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html), or if you want to access the built-in camera of the device, you have to invoke Java methods from the game logic (which is written is C / C++!).

### The Java -> C Part

Write a Java class. Declare one method `native`:

```
$ ls -F1
classes/
jni/
src/

$ nano src/com/example/jcj/Test.java
```

Test.java:

```
package com.example.jcj;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        doSomethingInC();
    }

    public static native void doSomethingInC();

    public static void doSomethingInJava() {
        System.out.println("Done something in Java!");
    }

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("hello_jcj");
    }
}
```

Invoke the "Java compiler" (`javac`), followed by the "C header and stub file generator" (`javah`):

```
$ javac -sourcepath src -d classes src/com/example/jcj/Test.java

$ javah -classpath classes -d jni com.example.jcj.Test

$ ls -F1 jni/
com_example_jcj_Test.h
```

Implement the C part:

```
$ nano jni/com_example_jcj_Test.c
```

com_example_jcj_Test.c:

```
#include "com_example_jcj_Test.h"
#include <stdio.h>

/*
 * Class:     com_example_jcj_Test
 * Method:    doSomethingInC
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_jcj_Test_doSomethingInC(JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz)
{
    printf("Done something in C!\n");
}
```

Compile the C source (Windows):

```
> REM TODO: Add this!
```

Compile the C source (Linux):

```
$ gcc -I{JAVA_HOME}/include
      -shared \
      -o libhello_jcj.so \
      jni/com_example_jcj_Test.c

$ ls -F1
classes/
jni/
libhello_jcj.so*
src/
```

Compile the C source (Mac OS X):

```
$ gcc -I${JAVA_HOME}/include \
      -shared \
      -o libhello_jcj.jnilib \
      jni/com_example_jcj_Test.c

$ ls -F1
classes/
jni/
libhello_jcj.jnilib*
src/
```

Run the Java application:

```
$ java -classpath classes com.example.jcj.Test
Done something in C!
```

### The C -> Java Part

Since you started your program in Java (instead of in C / C++), a JVM is already created. You don't need to create another one in the second part (C -> Java part), you just need to reuse the one already created. There are 2 ways to do it:

1. By using the Java Environment pointer (`JNIEnv*`) provided by the JNI call from the first part (Java -> C part)
2. By using the Java Virtual Machine pointer (`JavaVM*`) saved during `JNI_OnLoad()`

**(The answer is not finished and I will finish it later. If you like it, please vote me up for encouragement. Thanks!)**

References:

- [JNI Functions - Java Native Interface Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html)
- [The Invocation API - Java Native Interface Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html)
- [JNI Tips | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html)